# How do you specify authentication information for Mercurial as part of Jenkins? (mercurial_keyring)

Tags: mercurial, jenkins, mercurial-extension

I've got my code in a Mercurial repository (secured with a self-signed certificate) and I'm trying to set up Jenkins to work with it.

I've got the Mercurial plugin installed in Jenkins (pointing to an install of TortoiseHg on the Jenkins Server/Slaves) and the Jenkins Job is properly configured to grab the source from the repository.

When I build manually (ie, via the web interface) everything works as expected.

However, it seems like the polling of the repository does not succeed as I get output similar to the following:

```
Started on Apr 27, 2012 1:07:41 PM
[<jobname>] $ hg pull --rev default
warning: <MercurialServerIP> certificate with fingerprint e3:5f:5e:ea:4f:da:ef:a4:0b:4a:bb:00:e8:31:59:de:ce:d0:28:94 not verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting)
abort: mercurial_keyring: http authorization required but program used in non-interactive mode
[<jobname>] $ hg log --style <workspace>\<jobname>\tmp688470509422797505style --branch default --no-merges --prune 65d180b20a1e625841c8385709c86b83c3e10421
Done. Took 1.9 sec
No changes
```

I've previously done a manual clone of a repository so that I was able to enter the user's password to work with the Mercurial keyring extension for the authorization, but based on the error output it doesn't seem as though that's being applied.

How can I configure Jenkins or the machine running the build to do the polling successfully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be the *best* way to address the issue, but it worked for me and I'm able to move on.

**The only way I was able to figure out how to get the server to remember the password in my setup was to specify it manually in \mercurial.ini .**

NOTE: You may also have to remove the mercurial_keyring line from mercurial.ini. (This disables the keyring extension since we're specifying everything manually.)

I had previously believed that cloning a repository once on the server would let it remember the password, but this doesn't seem to work with the polling functionality in Jenkins (although it did work with my actual build scripts when they were executed on the server).

I'm not particularly pleased with having the password in plain text on the server, but until I find a better way to get the polling to work I can live with this.

Answer (score 0):

Using the "kilnauth extension" you can have you credentials stored on your machine. This way you don't have to configure anything special on Jenkins.

```
$ hg help kilnauth
kilnauth extension - stores authentication cookies for HTTP
repositories. This extension knows how to capture Kiln
authentication tokens when pushing over HTTP.
This means you only need to enter your login and password once;
after that, the FogBugz token will be stored in your home
directory, allowing pushing without a password.
```

For instructions on how to install it follow: http://kiln.stackexchange.com/questions/341/how-can-i-install-kilns-mercurial-extensions-manually